# Anime title featuring a swordswoman with one red eye, a young girl with a rabbit, and a giant monster with rabbit ears

Tags: story-identification, anime

The only info I have is [this short clip from TikTok](https://www.tiktok.com/t/ZTRRtPmbs/?k=1). Nobody will answer me over there. I was hoping you guys could help.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please [edit] a description of this show and a couple of screencaps into your question in case this gets taken down.

Answer (score 12):

It is actually a game, titled 非人学园 (*Extraordinary Ones*).

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/ExtraordinaryOnes):

> *Extraordinary Ones* is a free-to-play mobile Multiplayer Online Battle Arena created by NetEase Games of *Videogame/Onmyoji* fame. Unlike its fellow Chinese MOBAs such as *Arena of Valor*, it eschews traditional fantasy or quasi-realistic styles for a more anime-influenced aesthetic featuring a multitude of expies of various pop culture icons.

Comment: https://extraordinary-ones-asia.fandom.com/wiki/Alpha_White

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not expect an answer so fast 

Comment: @user153482: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].